# Suppressing page numbering in the first page of chapter in mainmatter but *not* in frontmatter

Tags: header-footer, chapters, page-numbering, front-matter

I am using the book class. I want to suppress page styles (page number, header, footer) in the first page of every chapter in my mainmatter, but *not* in `\frontmatter` - where I want to have roman numbers in the footer (right corner).

I can suppress page style in the first page of every chapter document-wide with:

```
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                \thispagestyle{empty}% original style: plain
                \global\@topnum\z@
                \@afterindentfalse
                \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother
```

but this imposes a `\pagestyle{empty}` in the first page of every "chapter"  in the frontmatter, too, so that the TOC pages are not numbered. I want the TOC pages to be numbered, but I don't know how to do this.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
% empty style for the first page of every chapter
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                \thispagestyle{empty}% original style: plain
                \global\@topnum\z@
                \@afterindentfalse
                \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother

\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{} % clear default layout
\fancyfoot{} % clear default layout
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
\fancyhead[L]{\sffamily \small \color{darkgray}\MakeUppercase{\bfseries        \leftmark}}  
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase \scshape \small \thepage}
}

\fancypagestyle{frontmatter}{%
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{frontmatter}% frontmatter page style
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage % with tocloft we need this
\listoffigures
\clearpage % with tocloft we need this
\listoftables
\clearpage

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{mainmatter}

\chapter{A}
\kant
\chapter{B}
\kant
\chapter{C}
\kant
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) provides the condition `\if@mainmatter` which you can use to condition on whether or not you're in the `\mainmatter` section of your document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
% empty style for the first page of every chapter, except in \frontmatter
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                \if@mainmatter
                  \thispagestyle{empty}% plain page style in mainmatter
                \else
                  \thispagestyle{plain}% empty page style outside of mainmatter
                \fi%
                \global\@topnum\z@
                \@afterindentfalse
                \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother

\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{} % clear default layout
\fancyfoot{} % clear default layout
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
\fancyhead[L]{\sffamily \small \color{darkgray}\MakeUppercase{\bfseries        \leftmark}}  
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase \scshape \small \thepage}
}

\fancypagestyle{frontmatter}{%
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{frontmatter}% frontmatter page style
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage % with tocloft we need this
\listoffigures
\clearpage % with tocloft we need this
\listoftables
\clearpage

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{mainmatter}

\chapter{A}
\kant
\chapter{B}
\kant
\chapter{C}
\kant
\end{document}
```

While I've used `empty` and `plain` as the chapter page styles in the mainmatter and frontmatter respectively, you can update this to whatever you want, or even create your own new ones.

Also note that `memoir` provides functionality for creating headers/footers, so you don't need [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) for this.

Answer (score 3):

The [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package provides the `\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{<style>}` command, which can be used just like `\pagestyle` but changes only the first page of each chapter. It's the same you are doing with `\thispagestyle{}`, but without explicitly renewing `\chapter`.